# Alternative syntax of combining multiple condition check

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax

I am implementing a simple if statement in c, where I am comparing the value of integer 'tile' to four other integers: w, a, s and d.

Here is my code:

```
if(tile == w || tile == a || tile == s || tile == d )
{
    printf("legal\n");
    return true;
}
```

While the above is correct, the syntax is tiresome. Is there a more elegant way of writing the condition "'tile' is one of the following integers..."

I'm a novice in programming so I apologise as I suspect the answer is very obvious. I've failed to find it addressed elsewhere though.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for Code Review.

Comment: Thanks. Im new here. I'll bear it in mind.

Comment: Notice how all the solutions in the answers rely on special cases and are *more complicated* than your question. You also have a naive notion of 'tiresome'. If you happen to have a situation with a particular bunch of values just test them. Otherwise the values should be in some (abstract) container per the rest of your code. Just write the most straightforward thing. That is what you should learn from this, not a bunch of contortions.

Comment: That is what I ended up implementing. I tried the switch (seems elegant) but it turns out it has some arcane restrictions:

Comment: @jadhachem No it is not. Code Review is for concrete code from a project, which this is not.

Comment: @CPlus What do you mean by "concrete code from a project", and how is this not? OP doesn't have pseudo-code here; it's their real, actual code. That's not to say they wouldn't need to add _more_ code for it to be on-topic there, but as it stands your criterion is unclear.

Comment: @TylerH We don't see where `title` is defined, or any of that, how this code is used, etc. Code Review is for complete programs.

Comment: @TylerH "concrete code from a project" seems to be a quote from Code Review's help center. You are correct, the argument is unclear. Unfortunately the hypo/example/stub + GBP close reason commonly causes people to be unclear. If you are curious I'll try to be clear in why the question is off-topic for CR. Rather than trying to mind-read, I personally believe the question falls under the Generic Best Practice reason. Where the user is asking for the best way to approach a specific problem -- 'how can I check if a number is within a set of numbers'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options i can think of...

**bitwise**

```
#define TILE_W 0x0001
#define TILE_A 0x0002
#define TILE_S 0x0004
#define TILE_D 0x0008

if (tile&(TILE_w|TILE_A|TILE_S|TILE_D))
{
    printf("legal\n");
    return true;
}
```

**switch-case**

```
switch (tile)
{
case w:
case a:
case s:
case d:
    printf("legal\n");
    return true;
default:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While i go with the first method, the second method is still tiresome and not worth the effort.

Comment: The first option only works if you can assert that `tile` is a power of 2 and each of the values is also a power of 2.  The second option only works if `tile` has type `int` or smaller and each of `w`, `a`, `s` and `d` is a constant within the range of type `int`. Neither option is a generic replacement for your `if` condition.

Comment: First case introduces the possibility that the value might not be exactly one of the options (e.g. maybe it is 3), so care must still be taken

Answer (score 3):

While [eyalm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41216620/2173917) is maybe the one you're looking for, just wanted to chime in to point you to a more important factor here (*as you mentioned, "I'm a novice in programming"*), which is "Write code which is easier for humans to understand".

While the bitwise approach is *shorter*, it generally appears to be more difficult to understand a maintain, as it grows.

A cleaner approach will be (*while it takes more effort to write the code*), stick to the `if ( a || b || c)` syntax, or a fall-though `switch` case. It gives better readability.

- In case your options grows longer (*that you may need a horizontal scroll bar*), you can consider adding a function to get the required value checked and use the return value in the condition in the `if` statement.

The bottom line is, there is no right or wrong way, only choose the way which make the code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for improvement can depend on values which you compare with.

If `w`, `a`, `s` and `d` are integer numbers that have consecutive values (e.g. 10, 11, 12 and 13), if-statement can use condition for boundaries:

```
 if( tile >= w && tile <= d) { printf("legal\n"); }
```

If values are disparate (e.g. 6, 32, 142, 55), you can use `switch`..`case` construction, like

```
 switch (tile)
 {
    case w:
    case a:
    case s:
    case d:
          printf("legal\n");
          break;
    default:
          printf("ILLEGAL\n");
          break;
 }
```

Also you can use setting flag in one or multiple `if` as

```
int legal = 0;

// checking can be in different places of code
if (tile == w)
    legal = 1;
if (tile == a || tile == s)
    legal = 1;
if (tile == d)
    legal = 1;

if( legal )
{
   printf("legal\n"); 
}
```

And consider storing `w`, `a`, `s` and `d` values as array of valid values, so loop can be used for checking:

```
int valArr[] = {101, 151, 333, 7}; // you can add any number of values here
int i;
int legal = 0;
for(i = 0; i < ( sizeof(valArr)/sizeof(valArr[0]) ); i++)
{
     if(valArr[i] == tile)
     {
         legal = 1;
         break;
     }
}
if( legal )
{
   printf("legal\n"); 
}
else
{
   printf("ILLEGAL\n");
}
```